# I'm using IdentityServer4 and I'm trying to access additional API endpoints on the same server with an Access token, always receiving 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm using .net core 2.2 with IdentityServer 4, trying to access additional API endpoints on the same server with an Access token, always receiving 401.

Startup.cs

```
        services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5555";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = LocalApi.ScopeName;
        });

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Caching.ClientStoreExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Caching.ResourceStoreExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Caching.CorsExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.IssuerUri = "https://localhost:5555";
        });
```

Configure :

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Endpoint:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("v1/info")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = LocalApi.PolicyName)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAccountInfo()
```

Result :

```
  info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
     Authorization was successful.
  info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult[1]
     Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 401
```

### UPDATE

API requests an access token from IdentityServer to access
IdentityServer custom endpoint API.
When trying to access IdentityServer endpoint api authenticated by
this access token that received , I'm receiving 401

[image: explanation]

Comment: did we miss `app.UseAuthorization();` this piece ?

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. it's not existed in my version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around on the source, seems like `AddLocalApiAuthentication` method make use of its own authentication schemes, as we can see [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Hosting/LocalApiAuthentication/LocalApiAuthenticationExtensions.cs#L48) and [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Hosting/LocalApiAuthentication/LocalApiAuthenticationHandler.cs#L20).

So, if we want to keep default authentication scheme as `IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, just keep the startup config and change the action endpoint to `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)]`.

But I was just curious... If I was right, this config was on our Identity provider service, so why should it accept a Jwt token from other Identity provider as we config it like

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5555"; // Other Identity provider here
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.Audience = LocalApi.ScopeName;
        });
```

Is there any special reason for this ? cause AFAIK, `AddLocalApiAuthentication` was created embracing Identity provider to accept it own credentials, not from others.

***UPDATE***

I just take a look at your link... probably replace `API 1` as Client might be more suitable.

Just simply change the config like this

```cs
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Some registers...
    services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();
    // No need for services.AddAuthentication(...).AddJwtBearer(...);
    services.AddIdentityServer(); // This one take care of all the AddAuthentication stuff.
    // Some registers...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Some registers...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    // Some registers...
}

// Controller
[HttpGet]
[Route("v1/info")]
[Authorize] // This should be enough, and in case it's still 401, try beblow
//[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.AuthenticationScheme, Policy = IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAccountInfo()
```

Ensure to attach the token with `Authorization` header format as `Bearer eyskeu...`. This worked on .net 3.1, I don't have 2.x version for a while

Comment: I have no other identityprovider, I will explain what I want to do: 1- I have requested an access token from my IdentityServer to let my API access my IdentityServer. * API ->(Client Credentials) IdentityServer -- Received Access token * API -> ( Acess Token ) to an endpoint api on IdentityServer

Comment: I saw it on your update... hope updated version answer help.